# Add object property value to combobox using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a ComboBox that I am filling with objects to select. I have a LifeCycleObject class with a few properties, one of which is Name and one is TypeID. I am trying to add the Name property to a ComboBox where TypeID = 4 or 5.

```
Linq Query
  _lcObjects = new List<LifeCycleObject>();      

  cbStep.Items.AddRange(_lcObjects.FindAll(
                                       x => x.TypeID == 5 || x.TypeID == 4
                                             ).ToArray());
```

Which works, but it adds the object Type of EMS.Action.Entities.LifeCycleObject, I can't select the correct one from a combobox where every item is the same, so how do I add the LifeCycleObject.Name instead of the Class name.

Comment: is this WinForms or WPF ?

Comment: Override `ToString()` for `LifeCycleObject`?

Comment: As usual in WinForms\WebForms you just need to specify `DisplayMember ="Name"` and `ValueMember=ID or Name'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and `Binding`:

```
cbStep.DisplayMember = "Name"; 
cbStep.DataSource = _lcObjects.FindAll(x => x.TypeID == 5 || x.TypeID == 4);
```

This way the names of your objects will be displayed in the `ComboBox`. And the `SelectedValue` property will hold the selected object.Note that in order to make this work `Name` should be a public property in your class not a field.

Comment: thank you, I wasn't aware of display member property of comboboxes

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing wrong with what you do. You are adding a list of `LifeCycleObject`s which you want to select from in your combo box. Now what causes the confusion is the fact that the combo box does not know how to display the objects, so it just calles `ToString` on the objects. But you likely didn’t overwrite the method, so it will just tell you what the object is called.

So one way would be to overwrite the `ToString` method so it returns the value of the `Name` property. A more elegant way however would be to tell the combo box how it should display those objects. How that works depends on what kind of combo box you have: With WPF, you can set the [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) property. With WinForms, you need to set the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property.